# Add span element to Jquery datepicker table cell

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using Woocommerce Bookings plugin which adds the jQuery datepicker calendar to the page. I want to add a span element to the generated table cells so I can show some info on hover via CSS.

I started down the road of listening for change events to the calendar and adding in the span element after the table was generated via jQuery however would prefer to hook into the datepicker function and add the span as the table is generated.

Is there a way to hook into the datepicker function to accomplish this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such hook available for this. You have to do it yourself.
You will find the datetime picker template at `/woocommerce-bookings/templates/booking-form/datetime-picker.php`

You can add a span or whatever you want there.

[Developers Docs for Woocommerce booking](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/woocommerce-bookings/developer-docs-bookings/)

[Template Listing with info](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bookings-templates/)

[Action and filter reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bookings-action-and-filter-reference/)

Comment: Hi thanks for that but I'd already read through all the docs and examined the templates. The datetime-picker.php does not help for manipulating the HTML generated by the calendar widget unfortunately :(.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to the question I asked but I decided to go another way with this to achieve the same result. I just used CSS pseudo selectors to add in boxes that appear on hover of bookable dates like so:

```
td.bookable a {
position:relative;
background-color:#b03d37!important;
background-image:none!important;
border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1)!important;
color:#fff!important;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

td.bookable a::before {
content:'this is a hover description';
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
background:#000;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
width:150px;
height:100px;
opacity:0;
visibility:hidden;
transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

td.bookable a:hover::before {
opacity:1;
visibility:visible
}
```

...again not specifically an answer to what I asked but still a solution (albeit a limited one) that works for the use case I have.